# DownloadsFolder crashes if using CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting

Tags: c#, download, win-universal-app

I create a file that I want to be automatically saved to the Downloads folder of a user. So I used:

```
StorageFile file = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt");
```

But if I create that file again, I get an error stating that file already exists. So I used:

```
StorageFile file = await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

However that also crashes with the error saying that the parameter does not fall within the expected range. But if I use:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Then it does create the file even if it exists, but I need to create/save the file in the Downloads folder for easier access for the user. I thought of this (attempted) solution because of the [issue described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35629586/attachment-not-appearing-in-outlook-2016) prevented me from adding an attachment to certain e-mail clients.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`CreateFileAsync (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241633.aspx) uses the **FailIfExists** option as the default. So when you create that file again, you get an error stating that file already exists.

For more info, see [CreationCollisionOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ReplaceExisting).

The `DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)`  method crashes with the error saying that the parameter does not fall within the expected range.

> Because the app can only access files in the Downloads folder that it created, you can't specify OpenIfExists or ReplaceExisting for this parameter.

Please see [`DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(String, CreationCollisionOption)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh996762.aspx) document’s Parameters section(the last paragraph).

You can use `DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("filename.txt", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName)` to create the file. 
It can automatically append a number to the base of the specified name if the file or folder already exists.

If you want to overwrite the exists file in DownloadsFolder. You can use [`FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to returns a storageFile object that was created to represent the saved file, and use [`FileIO.WriteTextAsync(IStorageFile, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method to write text to the specified file. It can overwrite the old file.

For example:

```
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Simple Line Files", new List<string>() { ".txt" });
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "filename";
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "hello");
}
```

Comment: It can't have a unique name, because I need to overwrite it, so GenerateUniqueName is not going to work. And I can't use a FileSavePicker because I just want to add the file to an easily accessible location. So instead of the DownloadsFolder, I'm using KnownFolders.ImageLibrary. Which works fine for I'm trying to do.